# Does MySQL optimize WHERE x >= 0 AND x <= 0 into WHERE x = 0?

Tags: mysql

I'm fairly new to MySQL , and in project I'm generating MySQL request, where a value can be different predefined ranges , with one special range composed of only the value `0`

I would like to know, if I need to handle this special case or just do

`BETWEEN 0 AND 0` and let MySQL optimize it

a  explain of the requests

`EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(*) FROM my_table WHERE field = 0`

`EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(*) FROM my_table WHERE field BETWEEN 0 AND 0`

`EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(*) FROM my_table WHERE field BETWEEN 0 AND 10`

all gives the same explain result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same plan, same optimization.   No, don't handle such minutia unless you can prove that you need to.

Even if one form were 20 milliseconds more expensive than another form, is it really worth adding an avenue for hard-to-understand bugs to infiltrate?

Answer (score 1):

The explain depends on the distribution of your data.
Let`s say you have millions of rows and an unique index on field.
In that case your explain will show an index seek or range scan depending on the conditions in WHERE.

You probably have few rows in the database so the explain is the same for all or your WHERE conditions return more than 30% of all rows so the optimizer decides for a table scan in all cases.

Comment: I see, so right now just by taking a look at the explain , I can't really know if MySQL optimize out the BETWEEN 0 AND 0, right ?.   my field is not unique, it's a age field, so the distribution is certainly around  10% for that value (the explain was made on a database with ~500k rows)

Comment: @allan.simon BETWEEN 0 AND 0 is probably interpreted as WHERE field=0.But even if the percentage is lower mysql might decide that it\`s faster to do a table scan than use the index,it`s not an exact number.

Comment: @allan.simon Try a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM..and the first 2 queries should return the same number of rows.I`m curious to the results returned by the third as opposed to the first 2.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this way:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SUM(*) FROM my_table WHERE field = 0
```

And let MySQL take care of the rest :)

Comment: as said, I do know that if i was writing a one shot request, i would always do `field = 0`,  but that require extra logic in my application code to handle this case, so the point of my question was "is it worth the extra code"